# ¿Cómo abrir cualquier tipo de archivo usando la librería Process?

Tags: vb.net

Estoy tratando de abrir archivos adjuntos de los cuales obtengo la ruta con una consulta SQL y al yo copiar y pegar la ruta en el explorador de archivos se abre el documento, por lo que si existe, la carpeta en la que se guardan es una carpeta compartida, pero al momento de yo tratar de abrir dichos archivos desde una aplicación windowsform aparece un error al ejecutar el process.start().
Quizás no sea relevante o si pero la carpeta compartida está en el servidor y requiere contraseña, yo tengo acceso y estoy ejecutando desde mi sesión donde tengo el acceso a dicha carpeta.

El error es este "An error occurred trying to start process '\bdsap-fg\DOCSAP\Electrica Industrial\Attachments\EIP220428D16_I_CCVG3357_ov503624_CDNCOMER.xml' with working directory 'C:\Users\eunice.garcia\Documents\desarrollos visual\Pagos\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows'. The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform."

Básicamente yo lleno un datagriedview con la ruta de los archivos y al hacer doble clic en cualquier celda con la ruta se debe abrir el archivo sin descargarlo.

Ya he probado de varias maneras mi código es el siguiente, todo lo que está comentado son varias pruebas que he hecho pero todas marcan el mismo error al llegar a la linea de Process.Start()

```
    Private Sub dtgArchivos_CellDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dtgArchivos.CellDoubleClick
        Try
            ' Verifica si se hizo doble clic en una celda válida (no en los encabezados)
            ' If e.RowIndex >= 0 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex = 2 Then
            ' Accede al valor de la celda en la que se hizo doble clic
            'Dim cellValue As String = dtgArchivos.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value.ToString

            'Process.Start("" & cellValue & "")
            ' MessageBox.Show("Valor de la celda: " & cellValue.ToString())
            '-------------------------------------------------------------

            'proceso = New Process
            'proceso.StartInfo.FileName = cellValue
            'Try
            '    proceso.Start()
            'Catch ex As Exception
            '    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            'End Try
            '-----------------------

            ' Verifica si se hizo doble clic en una celda válida
            'If e.RowIndex >= 0 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex = 2 Then
            '    ' Accede al valor de la celda en la que se hizo doble clic
            '    Dim cellValue As Object = dtgArchivos.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value

            '    ' Verifica si la celda contiene una ruta de archivo
            '    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(cellValue.ToString()) Then
            '        ' Abre el archivo usando el programa predeterminado
            '        Try
            '            Process.Start(cellValue.ToString())


            '        Catch ex As Exception
            '            ' Maneja cualquier error que pueda ocurrir al abrir el archivo
            '            MessageBox.Show("Error al abrir el archivo: " & ex.Message)
            '        End Try
            '    End If
            'End If
            '---------------------


            Dim filePath As String = "\\bdsap-fg\DOCSAP\Electrica Industrial\Attachments\EIP220428D16_I_CCVG3357_ov503624_CDNCOMER.xml"

            If System.IO.File.Exists(filePath) Then
                Process.Start(filePath)
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("El archivo no existe en la ubicación especificada.")
            End If


            'End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Valor de la celda: " & ex.Message)
        End Try
End Sub
```

También agregué el Imports System.Diagnostics  e incluso agregué la nuguet System.Diagnostics.Process
Si alguien pudiera apoyarme se lo agradecería muchísimo

Comment: Diría que no es un problema de tu código, si no de que en tu windows no tienes ninguna aplicación predeterminada para abrir los archivos con extensión .xml, o el que tienes predeterminado no es válido. Intenta abrir el archivo con doble click lo primero para ver si te lo abre o no.

Comment: @Pikoh Hola gracias por tomarte el tiempo, intenté lo que me indicaste y si se abren incluso les asigné programas predeterminados pero el acabo de descubrir que el problema es la ruta, ya que el nombre de la carpeta tiene un espacio y además debo indicar la ruta del programa con el que se deben abrir y como generalmente son programas de tipo xml, pdf o algún tipo de imágen decidí usar chrome quedando mi línea  de la siguiente manera:    
Process.Start("C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", filePath)

Ya solo me falta ver cómo manejar los espacios en la ruta

Answer (score 0):

Bueno al final para manejar la ruta con espacios se tuvo que enviar con comillas dobles como se haría en una ventana de comandos quedando mi código de la siguiente manera

```
 Dim cellValue As String = """" + dtgArchivos.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("ruta").Value.ToString + """"
            'Dim cellvalue As String = """\\Bdsap\DOCSAP\Electrica Industrial\Attachments\OC 36825 FG DFC.pdf"""

            Process.Start("C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", cellValue)
```

Lo coloco ya que probablemente a alguien le pueda ahorrar unos minutos de búsqueda